# Cayley-Hamilton Block Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

In Q4 d) I understand how to get the expression for A (using Q3), but I don't understand how you can then say that C is of the form described.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, because $C$ is a block diagonal matrix, we have
$$ C^² + C + I_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
        A^² & 0  \\
        0 & A^²  \\
        \end{pmatrix} +  \begin{pmatrix}
        A & 0  \\
        0 & A  \\
        \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
        I_2 & 0  \\
        0 & I_2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}  $$
which simplifies to
$$
C^² + C + I_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
        A^² + A + I_2 & 0  \\
        0 & A^² + A + I_2  \\
        \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: $I_n$ is the identity matrix of size  $ n$.

Comment: Is there another approach? If I didn't have the solution I wouldn't know what C is.

Comment: I am not aware of any other way I think. Since the degree of the above equation is 2, we can use **3** to find the matrix $A$ which is that given in **(d)**. This is a 2 by 2 matrix. Now we need a matrix of size 4 satisfying the equation for which I can only think of exploiting the properties of diagonal matrices.